# iTunes playback getting frequent (5+/min) dropouts

Tags: macos, itunes

I'm having the exact same symptoms as [this user](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/77615/itunes-11-stuttering-during-playback). However, I don't (like that user) have FileVault on, nor are my hard drives sleeping whenever possible (as per energy saving settings).

My music playback keeps dropping out for a second or so, several times per song (5+). No crazy CPU usage or anything like that.

Ideas?

Specs:

- Mid-2011 Mac Mini
- OSX 10.9.5
- 2.5GHz i5
- 8 GB DDR3
- SSD
- AMD Radeon HD 6630M 256MB
- iTunes 12.1.2.27

Comment: We need more info. Machine, OS, RAM, drive type, memory/swap/CPU usage from Activity Monitor, etc...

Comment: Could [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5551788?tstart=0) help you? please [edit](http://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/189645/edit) your question and add details of your hardware.

Comment: Do you have any other media players installed? Also check your sound output settings in System Preferences > Sound > Output. Also, try using hedphones, headset or different speakers. It could be the hardware problem

Comment: I have Quicktime. Output device is internal speakers.